# How can I use IdentityDBContex while inheriting from base DBContext

Tags: c#, inheritance, identity, dbcontext

I have multiple DBs in my project, all of them should derive from an abtract `BaseDbContext` that derives from  `DbContext`. My `BaseDbContext` contains new methods and some overrides of the `DbContext` methods. One of my DBs should work with identity so it should inherit from `IdentityDbContext` but it should also inherit my `BaseDbContext` since it needs the same logic. 
How can I accomplish this with a good design?

Two options I have thought about and their drawbacks are:

1. Make my `BaseDbContext` inherit from `IdentityDbContext`, that will create all the identity tables in all of my DBs when they are actually only needed in one.
2. Duplicate the code from `BaseDbContext` in the DB that needs to use the identity and inherit only from `IdentityDbContext`, that will result in all the bad design that comes with code duplication.

Is there a better way to do this? Should I settle for one of the listed options and if so which?

Comment: What version of .Net are you on?  .Net Core 3 lets you have a default implementation of an interface.  You could make `BaseDbContext` an interface, and then have the rest of your context's "implement" that interface, and just use the default implementation.  Then you can do the same for `IdentityDbContext`.

Otherwising, copying code for 1 other class doesn't seem exhaustive, and is what I would do in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

C# does not allow multiple inheritances. Therefore, technically you can't achieve this without either going for code duplication or using `IdentityDbContext` as your base dbcontext. However, one thing that you can do is to have an interface with all the functionalities that you want and then impediment it both `BaseDbContext` and `IdentityDbContext` finally you can have a third class containing the actual functionality that you want and then in your `BaseDbContext` and `IdentityDbContext` just call the functions of that class, this way you are avoiding duplicate implementation issue.

```
class A{
    int test(){
        //TODO: Complete
    }
}

interface IBaseDbContext {
   int test();
}

class MyIdentityDbContext:IBaseDbContext,IdentityDbContext  {
      private readonly _a;
      MyIdentityDbContext(A a){
          _a=a;
      }
      int test()=>_a.test();
} 

class MyDbContext:IBaseDbContext,DbContext {
      private readonly _a;
      MyDbContext(A a){
          _a=a;
      }
      int test()=>_a.test();
}
```

---

PS: take care of dbcontext options and required constructor inputs for you context, yourself, I just wanted to give you the rough idea.

PS2: If you are using .net core3+ you can take advantage of default interface implementation.